# Error parsing comments loading properties file on weblogic

Tags: java, xml, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

I'm using jdeveloper 11.1.7.1 and WebLogic 10.3.5.
When I try to load a simple xml properties file:

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PROPS_PATH);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.loadFromXML(fis);
```

I get an exception:

```
2016-09-21 10:26:13 ERROR PTProperties.<init>:37 - Exception: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLComment cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLComment cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
        at java.util.XMLUtils.importProperties(XMLUtils.java:114)
        at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:86)
```

The xml properties file has a simple comment `<!-- this is a comment -->` and if I remove it everything works.

I've removed "Oracle XML Parser v2" from the classpath of every project of the application but the error still remains.

I found this [bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7099658) on the oracle site but I have the same problem deploying the application on WebLogic 10.3.6 with jdk7.

Any suggestion to resolve?

Thank you.